# How to drop a particular element among others in a string

Tags: r, string

```
ID<-c(1:5)
string<-c("aaa-NA","NA", "bbb-NA-aaa,","bbb-ccc","NA-aaa-ccc")
mydata<-data.frame(ID,string)
```

I want to create a new variable by dropping `NA`, only when they are associated with other characters, like that:

```
  ID      string new_var
1  1      aaa-NA     aaa
2  2          NA      NA
3  3 bbb-NA-aaa, bbb-aaa
4  4     bbb-ccc bbb-ccc
5  5  NA-aaa-ccc aaa-ccc
```

Comment: How did you create this string.  Is it from `paste`?  I think the creation of 'string' would have been avoided.

Comment: Yes I created them from paste after grouping by the ID of individuals

Comment: I would have considered using `tidyr::unite(df1, string, col1, col2, col3, na.rm = TRUE, sep="-")` so that this step can be avoided

Comment: Or if you are pasting from a single column, try by removing the NAs i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(string = if(all(is.na(string))) NA_character else str_c(string[complete.cases(string)], collapse= "-"))`

Comment: I understand, I think this is a good option. I will try it and come back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mydata$new_var <- gsub("-NA|NA-","",mydata$string)
```